# Unable to clear the "altRecipient" attribute

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryservices

I seem to be experiencing a problem clearing the "altRecipient" attribute in Active Directory. When I run my program, it executes and returns successfully, but when I check either ADUC or ADSI Edit, the attribute is not cleared. Below is how I'm trying to clear the attribute:

```
termUser.Properties["altRecipient"].Clear();
```

I have also tried to clear the attribute by using:

```
termUser.Properties["altRecipient"].Value = null;
```

If I use the Clear() method on the "ipPhone" attribute, it works as expected. The only difference that I can see between the "ipPhone" attribute and the "altRecipient" attribute in ADSI Edit is that "ipPhone" is a *Unicode String* syntax whereas the "altRecipient" attribute has a *Distinguished Name* syntax.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: do you try to also set deliverAndRedirect to false : `termUser.Properties["deliverAndRedirect"].Value = false`;
Don't forgot to call `termUser.CommitChanges();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your response JPBLanc. I tried the "deliverAndRedirect" property and was still having a problem. I had a method that was setting three properties total and had the

```
termUser.CommitChanges();
```

being called at the end. I ended up calling

```
termUser.CommitChanges();
```

twice, once after

```
termUser.Properties["altRecipient"].Clear();
```

and again after setting the other two properties. It seems to be working now.....thank you for your help!